# How to Make Custom Shaped Layout in Android

Tags: android, shapes

I'm making a bottom navigation bar, of custom shape
Like this =>

[image: BottomToolbar]

So I tried using LinearLayout with a FAB on it, as I dont know much about custom shapes,
but my idea not working as, when I scroll my webView bottombar hides, but fab doesn't. Anyways this is a bad method.

So, What I want is to make a custom shaped bottombar,
please help me make it, or just simple guiding would be helpful,

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]Create a drawable with the below fields

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="15dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ED7D31" /> //Color of youe choice
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp"
        android:gravity="top|center">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ED7D31" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and in the XML file add it as a background like below

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list" /> //Your drawable name here
```

Comment: Shadows Not Dropping, Why ?

Comment: Can You Help Me for Shadows ?

Comment: Anyways ThankYou So so Much for Help :)

Comment: Shadow where ? I didn't find shadow in your Question

Comment: Add  android:elevation="4dp" in your XML file like added in the Answer

Comment: I'm Sorry I Forgot to Ask, But I thought It Would not cause any issue with shadows.
Please help me for this too Rakshit if You can :) else no problem

Comment: Elevations not working after adding background drawables

Comment: elevation will work only above API level 21 through XML

Comment: Anyways, I'm Marking This as Accepted :)

Comment: My API is 25
Still Not working, Maybe Bcz I added Drawable