# How to create a rounded layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-button

I want to create a layout contains a map, main circle button, and a few buttons below.
I found it easy to create this with straight lines that separate the map and the layout below.
However, I don't have any clue how to do this with the nicely rounded layouts as shown in the picture.

Can someone guide me on how it's done?

[image: demo]

Answer (score 0):

Actually i guess you must use special library for layout shape (for this shape in image) but you can use this code for button view

```
<ImageButton
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp" // drawable right click -> new -> vector asset
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />


 shape.xml in drawable folder

 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
  </shape>
```

Comment: Maybe you can try this   https://stackoverflow.com/a/41597463/8894022